# I wanted to draw a circle in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I was making a dice gamein Javascript.

Someone told me to break that problem into many functions and create each app for each function.

So, I am now breaking the whole dice game into various functions such as drawing circles etc.

So, i like to create a circle (The dots on the dice), and for that; i used the initial source code and kept the useful code that helps me to draw an arc, ... but that is not working. Can anyone figure out why?

I think I missed some values to pass in the function, but I don't know if it is the problem?

I have tried to pass values inside the draw1() but that is not working

```js
var cwidth = 400;
var cheight = 300;
var dicex = 50;
var dicey = 50;
var dicewidth = 100;
var diceheight = 100;
var dotrad = 6;
var ctx;

function init() {
  draw1();
}

function draw1() {
  var dotx;
  var doty;
  ctx.beginPath();
  dotx = dicex + 0.5 * dicewidth;
  doty = dicey + 0.5 * diceheight;
  ctx.arc(dotx, doty, dotrad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

init();
```

I want the same program to make a small circle

Comment: Someone has already done this here: https://codepen.io/dzsobacsi/pen/pjxEOK
But for clarity, I think you're trying to draw one "die."  Dice is the plural of die.  Finally, I would recommend using images rather than trying to draw them yourself, but I realize you're just trying to learn, so... have at it!

Comment: When writing a question then you should post a minimal, complete example of the code that can be executed. And explain where exactly you have a problem. Otherwise it is not clear if you problem is that the code does not run at all because `ctx` is not initialized or if it is another problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few problems with your initial code, mostly down to variables being undefined. When you declare a variable, it's only defined if you give it a value. That means that code such as:

```
var ctx;
```

Creates a variable called `ctx`, but its value is `undefined`. This means that when you try and do things like

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

You'll get an error, because `undefined` doesn't have a property `beginPath`.

What you need to do in order to fix this is initialise variables as you declare them. In fact, it's rarely a good idea to define a variable without initialising it.

I've added a function here to create a canvas, and you can then use that canvas object to initialise your `ctx` variable. Here's how that might look:

```js
var cwidth = 400;
var cheight = 300;
var dicex = 50;
var dicey = 50;
var dicewidth = 100;
var diceheight = 100;
var dotrad = 6;

function init() {
  draw1();
}

function addCanvas(width, height) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  return canvas;
}

function draw1() {
  var dotx;
  var doty;
  var canvas = addCanvas(cwidth, cheight)
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.beginPath();
  dotx = dicex + 0.5 * dicewidth;
  doty = dicey + 0.5 * diceheight;
  ctx.arc(dotx, doty, dotrad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);

  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>die</title>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="draw1()">
    <canvas id="canvas"width="400"height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
      nope unsp browser
    </canvas>
    <script>
      var cwidth = 400;
      var cheight = 300;
      var dicex = 50;
      var dicey = 50;
      var dicewidth = 100;
      var diceheight = 100;
      var dotrad = 6;
      var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = c.getContext('2d');;
          function draw1() {
          var dotx;
          var doty;
          ctx.beginPath();
          dotx = dicex + 0.5 * dicewidth;
          doty = dicey + 0.5 * diceheight;
          ctx.arc(dotx, doty, dotrad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.closePath();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```